# Check toll count, rate and address in a route in google maps

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am working on a driver app and requirement is to get the toll details between the route. In Details it should be Lat, long of the tolls, address, name of the toll and toll rate.

Can you please suggest me how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet available as far as Google APIs are concerned, but who knows maybe they will implement this in the near future; for this is one of the most in-demand feature that many users are looking forward to.